# Apache CloudStack: Guest VMs not able to reach to physical gateway (local network)

Tags: apache-cloudstack

### Issues:

Guest VMs in Apache CloudStack can ping each other, Host can ping all VMs, but guest VMs could not ping the physical gateway. Also, VMs are not accessible from outside the Cloud Stack.

### Environment:

###### Apache CloudStack setup as private could.

- Host OS: Ubuntu 20.04
- Hypervisor: KVM
- CloudStack Version:  4.15.2.0
- Networking: Basic Networking - Flat model
- defaultGuestNetwork range - 10.1.24.230 - 254
- iptable and firewall disabled.

###### Physical Network:

- Router/Gateway: 10.1.24.1 (1-220 reserved for DHCP)(Net Mask 255.255.255.0)
- Host is connected to the router through 4 ports.
- The host has 4 interfaces with bonded to bond0 and bond1 (only bond0 is used). bond0 attached to cloudbr0 with IP 10.1.24.11

All the system VMs and the virtual router are reachable from the host but not from outside.
(with IPs 10.1.24.230, 231, and 232 respectively)

###### Guest VMs

- OS currently in use is RockyLinux 8
- No firewall nor iptables is enabled.
- static networking is used with IP assigned in configuration and gateway set as 10.1.24.1

The management server is outside CloudStack running on other infra in the same network at IP 10.1.24.14

Earlier I had added IP range 10.1.25.2 to 10.1.25.100 in the GuestNetworks in the CloudStack and IP 10.1.25.1 assigned to the physical router. This setup worked okay with some network issues such as slow network and packet losses. There was a frequent drop in connection.

But recently nothing works. Any VM on IP range 10.1.24.x does not connect outside CLoudStack.

All guest VMs can communicate with each other, and I can ping them from the Host machine. But guest VMs can not access outside physical network or gateway.

I have seen a bit similar post with a bit different environment but it was not helpful.([Unable to ping and connect cloud stack vm instance ip from the same local network](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49295659/5736100))

Answer (score 0):

**Check from guest vm**

ping to your LAN gateway or your LAN any machine. also tracert to LAN gateway.

Check from LAN machine to guest vm ping

**ping to your guest vm**

Adding Ingress and Egress Rules to a Security Group

See ACS [Security Group](http://docs.cloudstack.apache.org/en/latest/adminguide/networking/security_groups.html)

See video for [allow this rules.](https://youtu.be/AZaYp_-Hamk)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but I have already tried these. The issue was probably due to network bonding on the host machine. bond0 on the host machine was using two interfaces connected to the same switch. Is it possible that this was causing the issue?
Currently, I reinstalled my host with recommended Centos7 with a simple bridge on a single ethernet interface. It's working fine now.